# PDO - Record insertion issue?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have used php and PDO mysql to insert a record. But does not affect success result.

What is the problem?

The error text is:

> DataBase Error: The user could not be added.
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line
>   2failed

```
<?php //Post Params 
    $txt_studid ='RU010/08' ;//trim($_POST['txt_studid']);  
    $cost_year =1 ;//trim($_POST['status']);  
    $txt_tution = 700;//trim($_POST['txt_tution']);  
    $txt_food = 600;//trim($_POST['txt_food']);  
    $txt_accom = 500 ;//trim($_POST['txt_accom']);  
?>

<?php //Query 

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=erca_db', 'root', '');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    try {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO st_costshare(stud_id, template_id, Tuition_fee, food_fee, Accomod_fee)
    VALUES(:studid, :cost_id, :tution, :food, :accomod");
        $stmt->bindValue(":studid", $txt_studid);
        $stmt->bindValue(":cost_id", $cost_year);
        $stmt->bindValue(":tution", $txt_tution);
        $stmt->bindValue(":food", $txt_food);
        $stmt->bindValue(":accomod", $txt_accom);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "DataBase Error: The user could not be added.<br>".$e->getMessage();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "General Error: The user could not be added.<br>".$e->getMessage();
    }

    if ($stmt->rowCount()>0) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "failed";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you post your table structure?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Closing tag issue. Forget to close values closing bracket

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO st_costshare(stud_id, template_id, Tuition_fee, food_fee, Accomod_fee)

VALUES(:studid, :cost_id, :tution, :food, :accomod)");
                                                 ^^^// missing
```